# Flutter - Access ThemeData.primarySwatch in widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I have this themeData:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vepo/fonts.gen.dart';

import 'theme_utils.dart';

MaterialColor primarySwatch = generateMaterialColor(primaryColorMid);
MaterialColor lightGreenSwatch = generateMaterialColor(lightGreenColorMid);
MaterialColor accentSwatch = generateMaterialColor(accentColor);

const primaryColorMid = Color(0xFF379e97);
const lightGreenColorMid = Color(0xFF5ccc89);
const darkBackgroundColor = Color(0xff303030);
const accentColor = Color(0xff3F51B5);
const errorColor = Color(0xffb03e3e);

Color initialGradientColor = lightGreenSwatch[300];
Color endGradientColor = primarySwatch[900];
Color blueText = lightGreenSwatch[500];

ThemeData homeTheme = ThemeData(
  accentColor: primaryColorMid,
  primarySwatch: primarySwatch,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primary: primarySwatch[500],
      secondary: accentSwatch[500],
      surface: Colors.white,
      background: primarySwatch,
      error: Colors.red[50],
      onBackground: Colors.white,
      onError: errorColor,
      onPrimary: Colors.white,
      onSecondary: Colors.white,
      onSurface: blueText,
      primaryVariant: Colors.white,
      secondaryVariant: Colors.white),
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.standard,
  canvasColor: primarySwatch,
  fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound,
  buttonColor: Colors.white,
  errorColor: errorColor,
  inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
    filled: true,
    alignLabelWithHint: true,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 22,
      horizontal: 26,
    ),
  ),
  buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
      height: 50,
      minWidth: 200,
      disabledColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.white)),
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: endGradientColor,
        onSurface: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
        minimumSize: const Size(200, 50),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 60),
        elevation: 20,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: blueText,
            fontFamily: FontFamily.hind)),
  ),
  textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 36.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound),
      headline2: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 55.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: primarySwatch[900].withOpacity(0.4),
          fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound),
      subtitle1: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
      caption: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontFamily: FontFamily.hind,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
      button: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: blueText,
          fontFamily: FontFamily.hind),
      bodyText2: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: FontFamily.varelaRound,
          color: primaryColorMid)),
);
```

but when I try to access `Theme.of(context).primarySwatch` it says:

> The getter 'primarySwatch' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeData'. Try
> importing the library that defines 'primarySwatch', correcting the
> name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field
> named 'primarySwatch'.

Why can't I access `theme.primarySwatch` from widgets? I also want to have access to `accentSwatch` which is not a field on `ThemeData`, is it somehow possible to add fields to ThemeData so I can use different theme dependent color shades by using swatches?

Something like this:

```
extension VpThemeData on ThemeData {
  MaterialColor accentSwatch(MaterialColor color) {
    return color;
  }
}
```

Have not got that working yet as I try calling it like:

```
ThemeData homeTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: primarySwatch,
  accentSwatch: accentSwatch(accentSwatch),...
```

Get error:

> The named parameter 'accentSwatch' isn't defined.

Comment: I've just discovered `primaryColorDark` on ThemeData which suits my needs.

Answer (score 7):

The answer you're looking for is `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary`.

From the API reference for ThemeData:

> Typically, only the brightness, primaryColor, or primarySwatch are specified. That pair of values are used to construct the colorScheme.

Comment: This fails with `Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Color'` if you try `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary[100]` while `Colors.purple[100]` works

Comment: @Kris I think they mean not to get a specific shade of the primary color, rather, just to use primary. But I agree it makes no sense to not allow access to different shades, if it "allegedly" uses the whole swatch that you specified to construct a theme.